# Dask compute() blocks and does not do anything

Tags: tensorflow, dask

I have a TensorFlow model that only uses 2 cores during training. I have 8 cores and want to train a bunch of these models on different random samples to compare. I thought I would save time by training 4 models in parallel.

```
import dask.bag as db
seeds = db.from_sequence(range(10), npartitions=4)
accuracies = seeds.map(lambda seed: train_and_get_accuracy(seed))
print(accuracies.compute())
```

`compute()` just blocks indefinitely and there is no CPU use. What did I mess up?

I looked at http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/inspect.html and tried printing `accuracies.dask`. I think it looks fine:

```
{('from_sequence-41b72669c9abaeca2236693465a55891', 0): [0, 1, 2],
 ('from_sequence-41b72669c9abaeca2236693465a55891', 1): [3, 4, 5],
 ('from_sequence-41b72669c9abaeca2236693465a55891', 2): [6, 7, 8],
 ('from_sequence-41b72669c9abaeca2236693465a55891', 3): [9],
 ('map-lambda-db55048968394cb7b842de6a78e7ee7d', 0): (<function reify at 0x7f9b8355d268>,
                                                      (<class 'map'>,
                                                       <function <lambda> at 0x7f9b78216400>,
                                                       ('from_sequence-41b72669c9abaeca2236693465a55891',
                                                        0))),
 ('map-lambda-db55048968394cb7b842de6a78e7ee7d', 1): (<function reify at 0x7f9b8355d268>,
                                                      (<class 'map'>,
                                                       <function <lambda> at 0x7f9b78216400>,
                                                       ('from_sequence-41b72669c9abaeca2236693465a55891',
                                                        1))),
 ('map-lambda-db55048968394cb7b842de6a78e7ee7d', 2): (<function reify at 0x7f9b8355d268>,
                                                      (<class 'map'>,
                                                       <function <lambda> at 0x7f9b78216400>,
                                                       ('from_sequence-41b72669c9abaeca2236693465a55891',
                                                        2))),
 ('map-lambda-db55048968394cb7b842de6a78e7ee7d', 3): (<function reify at 0x7f9b8355d268>,
                                                      (<class 'map'>,
                                                       <function <lambda> at 0x7f9b78216400>,
                                                       ('from_sequence-41b72669c9abaeca2236693465a55891',
                                                        3)))}
```

What else can I check to understand what's going on? It's an Ubuntu 16.04 system.

Comment: I guess TensorFlow does a lot of magic of its own. Is it perhaps not possible to run it with Dask?

Comment: Well it works alright without TensorFlow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try using Threads

By default dask.bag parallelizes using separate processes on your computer.  This is ideal for pure Python code (because of the GIL) but may not be ideal for numeric code like Tensorflow, especially if the Tensorflow library doesn't play well with forked processes (which may be the case?)

You can do this globally by setting the following

```
import dask
dask.set_options(get=dask.threaded.get)
```

or setting `get=` in the compute call

```
accuracies.compute(get=dask.threaded.get)
```

#### Consider using dask.delayed

Dask.bag provides a pretty simple interface, somewhat similar to the Spark RDD.  For more complex algorithms in the future, you might also try [dask.delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed.html).

Comment: It gives me a ~30% speedup as opposed to the 4x I was hoping for. I guess TensorFlow keeps a lot of locks. But at least it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Tensorflow may also be using all of your cores already?  You might also try the distributed scheduler.  See http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/scheduler-choice.html